Is it valid to ask about whether a given minifig is an official one?
My wife received, via a piece of gift purchasing software, a minifig of Batman with some odd touches such as coming with two large guns rather than any sort of Batarang or grapnel device. Looking through the tour for the site, it looks like the emphasis is on bricks and sets. Is it valid for me to post photos of the minifig and to ask about its provenance?

We already have a few questions about mini-figure authenticity (and other elements), along with a few tips about recognising them:
How can I tell if minifigures are custom-made or LEGO Originals?
If those don't help, then by all means post a question with some pictures :)
